# How to implement preloading in gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm using [gorm](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#preloading-eager-loading).

I have an issue bellow, hope somebody can help me resolve or explain more about that

```
type User struct {
    ID        int
    Name      string
    Addresses []Address
}

type Address struct {
    UserID   int `gorm:"index;not null"`
    Address string
    City     string
    Zipcode  int
    Country  string
}

if err := db.Select("name").Preload("Addresses").Find(&users).Error; err != nil {
    // Display error message
} else {
    //
}
```

Result:

```
[
    {
      "created_at": "2017-04-02T00:07:59Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-04-02T00:07:59Z",
      "name": "Richard"
    }
  ]
```

SQL log:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.deleted_at IS NULL AND ((1 <> 1))
```

Expect result:

```
[
  {
    "created_at": "2017-04-02T00:07:59Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-02T00:07:59Z",
    "name": "Richard",
    "addresses": [
      {
        "address": "No 1, Street 5",
        "city": "New York",
        "country": "US"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have researched some other post on StackOverflow but don't  see any solutions

Comment: Why don't you turn on logging and see if the generated SQL is what you expect?  `db.LogMode(true)` before your `db.Preload`, and then let us know what it says.  If it's what you expect, show us your db structure and the relevant data.

Comment: @dave only see SELECT query on users table

Comment: I'm surprised you get any results at all since `AND ((1 <> 1))` would tend to exclude everything from your `SELECT` query. Are you sure the results you're getting aren't some kind of default results?

Comment: @DavidFaber thank for your comment, I think I was wrong when debug to show SQL query so it's the wrong log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select missing `id` fields so preloading was not applied. Bellow code will be resolve issue

```
if err := db.Select("id, name").Preload("Addresses").Find(&users).Error; err != nil {
    // Display error message
} else {
    //
}
```